# Android TestCase how to get android.support.v4.FragmentTabHost's content view

Tags: android, testcase

I have an `Activity` with `android.support.v4.FragmentTabHost` which I want to test.

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/homeFragement"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/line_color" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bottom_bgcolor" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how I initialize the `TabHost`:

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabContent); 
int count = 4; 
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
    String title = getString(getTitleForIndex(i)); 
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(title); 
    tabSpec.setIndicator(createButtonView(i)); 
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec, mFragments[i], null); 
}
```

Now in my TestCase, `test_fragment()` method:

```
ActivityMonitor addMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(MainEntryActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
MainEntryActivity mainEntryActiviy = (MainEntryActivity) addMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(3000);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost fragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) mainEntryActiviy.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
fragmentTabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
```

It works and the `TabHost` has switch to tab 4.

How can I get the content of `TabHost` which should be a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that extends from `fragment` with a corresponding xml layout file, and in the `onCreateView` of the fragment class inflate the corresponding layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView()
{
     View view = inflator.inflate(R.id.your_layout_xml);
     return view;
}
```